# Coercive functionals and minimizing sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations, coercive

My course notes provide just a brief mention to a common technique used in calculus of variations, but I can't understand it.

Don't expect total rigor, since it's just a mention.

Let $G:X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a function where $X$ is a sufficiently regular function space. My notes define $G$ to be **coercive** iff its sublevels are precompact (I think that this means that its sublevels have compact closure).

My notes then affirm that if $G$ is coercive and lower semicontinous then the accumulation points of minimizing sequences (i.e. sequences $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ such that $G(x_n)\to \inf \ G$) are minimum points. Is this trivial? Because I don't see it.

Moreove is it assured that at least a minimizing sequence has an accumulation point?

I have never studied calculus of variations, so please try to be basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $m = \inf_{x \in X} G(x)$. By the definition of infimum, we can select $x_n \to x$ such that $G(x_n) \to m$.
Since it is coercive, so there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ such that it is convergent and we still denote this subsequence by $x_n$. Suppose $x_n \to x_0$.

Moreover, $G$ is lower semicontinuous implies $G(x_0) \leq \liminf_{x \to x_0} G(x) \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} G(x_k) = m$.

On the other hand, $m = \inf_{x \in X} G(x) \geq G(x_0)$. So $G(x_0) = m$.

Comment: Why the fact that $G$ is coercive implies that $\{x_n\}$ admits a convergent subsequence. Clearly $\{x_n\}\subseteq G^{-1}[m,\infty)$ but $G^{-1}[m,\infty)$ is not a sublevel so we cannot say that it's (pre)compact.

Comment: @Kandinskij For $n$ sufficiently large, $G(x_n) \leq m +1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Premise**. While I was working on the following one, a previously given answer was accepted: nevertheless I hope that mine could still be useful to someone.

The result is apparently well known though not trivial: it basically is the consequence of two facts

1. First recall the following propertiy of lower semicontinuous functions:
   **Theorem** (theorem 4 in [2]). Let $X$ be a topological space. A function $G:X \to \overline{\Bbb R}$ is lower semicontinuous if and only if its sublevel
   $$
   G^{-1}(]-\infty, a])=\{x\in X \mid G(x)\le a\}$$ is closed for every $a\in\overline{\Bbb R}$.
    The proof is a very simple consequence of definition of lower semicontinuity.
   This property, jointly with the precompactness of the sublevels $G^{-1}(]-\infty, a])$ due to coercivity, implies directly that these sets are compact (since the closure of a closed set is the set itself).
2. As @Ning wrote in is answer, due to the very definition of $\inf_{x\in X} G(x)$, we can define a minimizing sequence $\{x_n\}$ conveying to it and, due to the compactness of the sub level sets, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x\in X$.

**Final note**: The route for proving this result I followed here was inspired by the informal notes given in [1], chapter 2, §2.1, pp. 9-12. The authors deal with this problem in a less general setting (they assume in the end that $X$ is a Banach space) but nevertheless they show how semicontinuity, the structure of sublevels and the coercivity, defined in the traditional way as it is customary for Banach spaces, i.e.
$$
\lim_{\substack{\|x\|_{X}\to\infty\\ x\in X}}\frac{G(x)}{\|x\|_{X}}=\infty
$$
of the given functional interact in order to prove an existence theorem.

**References**

[1] Claudio Baiocchi, António Capelo, *Variational and quasivariational inequalities. Applications to free boundary problems*, translated from the Italian by Lakshmi Jayakar, a Wiley-Interscience publication. Chichester-New York-Brisbane-Toronto-Singapore: John Wiley and Sons, pp. ix+452 (1984), [MR745619](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=745619), [Zbl 0551.49007](https://zbmath.org/0551.49007).

[2] I. A. Vinogradova (originator), "[Semicontinuous function](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Semicontinuous_function)". *Encyclopedia of Mathematics*, ISBN 1402006098.